# Sharepoint list item count

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list which is having items greater that 5000, now i have a requirement to show the number of items in that list on a web page.Can anybody help me on getting the total items count . The normal list view threshold is set as 5000. I need only the count.

Thanks

Comment: Pls share the code u are using right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your SP admins to increase the size of a return query to greater than 5000 rows in Central Admin.

If you are using the SP object model in Visual Studio, just loop through the list in increments of the limit until you run out to get the total rows.

There's also a total rows/items property in the SPList object.